# Fire a remote bootstrap modal when clicking a form submit button, remote modal content then has form data to be displayed?

Tags: html, node.js, express, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I'm having trouble finding a way to accomplish this.

I'm using Node.js, Bootstrap 3, and express

I want to start on a form page.  When the user fills out the form they click on submit.  Here I want to fire a remote modal.  (Have no trouble accomplishing this from a regular link or button.)

This kicks off a post.  How can I then fire a remote modal and pass the form data from the post to it so a new remote page with answers can show up in the modal window over the original form page.

Here is code I have:

Form Jade (cover-form.jade):

```
html
    head
        meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        title= title
        link(href="/stylesheets/coverform_custom.css" rel="stylesheet")
    body
        .modal.fade(id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true")
            .modal-dialog.wide-modal
                .modal-content
        form.form-horizontal(id="coverform" name="coverform" method="post" action="")
            .LoginBox.LoginText
                fieldset.animated.fadeInUp
                    // Form Name
                    legend.LoginText &nbsp;Cover Strategy
                    // Text input
                    .form-group
                        label.col-xs-4.control-label(for='symbol') Stock Ticker:
                        .col-xs-5
                            input#symbol.form-control.input-xs(type='text', name='symbol', placeholder='example: AAPL', autofocus, required)
                            span.help-block Enter Stock Symbol (all capitals)
                    // Text input
                    // Select Basic
                    .form-group
                        label.col-xs-4.control-label(for='optiondate') Option Date:
                        .col-xs-5
                            select#optiondate.form-control(name='optiondate' required)
                                - for opdate in OptionDates
                                    option(value="#{opdate.OptionDate}") #{moment(opdate.OptionDate).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY')}
                            span.help-block Date the option closes.
                    .form-group
                        label.col-xs-4.control-label(for='strikeprice') Strike Price:
                        .col-xs-5
                            input#strikeprice.form-control.input-xs(type='number', name='strikeprice', placeholder='example: 100.00',  pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?", min="0", step="0.50", required)
                            span.help-block Strike price of the option.
                    // Text input
                    .form-group
                        label.col-xs-4.control-label(for='optionprice') Option Selling Price:
                        .col-xs-5
                            input#optionprice.form-control.input-xs(type='number', name='optionprice', placeholder='example: .45', pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?", min="0", step="0.05", required)
                            span.help-block Price the option is selling for.
                    // Button
                    .form-group
                        label.col-xs-4.control-label(for='submit')
                        .col-xs-4
                            button#submit.btn.btn-primary(name='submit' type='submit') Submit
        script(src='/javascripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js')
        script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Remote Modal Jade (Not referencing any form data yet) answer.jade:

```
html
    body
        .modal-header
            button(type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true")&times;
            h4.modal-title(id="myModalLabel") This Is An Awesome Title
        .modal-body 
            p This Body Is Great
        .modal-footer
            button.btn.btn-default(data-dismiss="modal") Close
```

app.js for Routing:

```
...

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/cover', cover.coverForm);
app.post('/cover', cover.doCover);

...
```

cover.js:

```
exports.doCover = function(req, res) {
    var mystockdata = [];
    console.log("Here is the symbol I got:    " + req.body.symbol);
    StockPrices.find({
        Symbol: req.body.symbol
    })
        .sort('Date')
        .exec(function(err, stockdata) {
            if (!err) {
                stockdata.forEach(function(stockdata) {
                    mystockdata.push({
                        "MarketDate": stockdata.Date,
                        "Open": stockdata.Open,
                        "High": stockdata.High,
                        "Close": stockdata.Close,
                        "Volume": stockdata.Volume
                    });
                });
                console.log("Here is the stock Data:    " + stockdata);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.render('answer', {});
        });
};
```

So my question really is how Do i route this so that on click of submit on cover-form.jade I can execute a bootstrap modal and fire the post rendering the modal content using the doCover function?

Maybe I am approaching this completely wrong as well, not sure how to accomplish what I want.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to make it work but not remotely

Bootstrap 3 buttons are submit type by default, so I used a standard one that fired a modal...

```
button#submit.btn.btn-primary(name='submit' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal") Submit
```

Then I put the standard Bootstrap modal stuff at the top of my page:

```
.modal.fade(id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true")
  .modal-dialog.wide-modal
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') ×
        h4.myModalLabel.modal-title 
        | #{title}
      .modal-body
          #container(style="width:90%; height:400px;")
      .modal-footer
        button.btn.btn-primary(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Close
```

Then the real trick was to check if the route fired from app.js was a post or a get.  If it was a post meaning the form was submitted, then I used jQuery to show the modal.  Otherwise it tries to show but immediately routes back to just the form.  I did this by checking a variable that is only rendered on the post function (strikeprices):

```
script.
  $(document).ready(function(){

    if(#{strikeprices}){
      $('#myModal').modal('show')
    }

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
      $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
  });
```